# .htaccess RewriteRule hates "Portfolio" word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, domain.com/About is calling to file About.php just fine same as domain.com/portfolio works with portfolio.php.

Problem - domain.com/Portfolio does not work with Potfolio.php, error:

```
/Portfolio/.php was not found on this server.
```

I have no idea why it does this just with this one particular word, it gives headache already. Any ideas?

PS. There is no Portfolio folder

Update: error.log

```
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/ -> Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] rewrite 'Portfolio/' -> 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add per-dir prefix: Portfolio/.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] internal redirect with /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff8b68/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff8b68/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff8b68/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff8b68/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:46.304340 2015] [:error] [pid 4924:tid 1660] [client ::1:50145] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/notfound.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/ -> Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] rewrite 'Portfolio/' -> 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add per-dir prefix: Portfolio/.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] internal redirect with /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:47.911142 2015] [:error] [pid 4924:tid 1660] [client ::1:50145] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/notfound.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/ -> Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] rewrite 'Portfolio/' -> 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add per-dir prefix: Portfolio/.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.051543 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2a50/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] internal redirect with /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.067143 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffab70/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.067143 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffab70/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.067143 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffab70/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.067143 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffab70/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.067143 2015] [:error] [pid 4924:tid 1660] [client ::1:50145] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/notfound.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/ -> Portfolio/
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] rewrite 'Portfolio/' -> 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add per-dir prefix: Portfolio/.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ffaa70/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] internal redirect with /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio -> C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php -> Portfolio/.php
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] applying pattern '^([^\\.]+)$' to uri 'Portfolio/.php'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.207543 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4924:tid 1660] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50145] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#434100][rid#2ff2b50/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:48.223143 2015] [:error] [pid 4924:tid 1660] [client ::1:50145] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/notfound.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.413157 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.459957 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.647158 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.693958 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.693958 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.693958 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:56.693958 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5620:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5088
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:57.458359 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5088:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:57.692360 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5088:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jul 10 12:26:57.739160 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5088:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Do you have access to your rewrite log?

Comment: rewrite log? let me google that

Comment: Quick instruction how do I access rewrite log?

Comment: Look for `RewriteLog`  directive in your config file. You can use this directive to define a rewrite log file!

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell me about your server version (2.2? 2.4?)  and OS!

Comment: Im using XAMPP 5.5.19 [PHP: 5.5.19] on windows 7. About the RewriteLog I made this line `RewriteLog "log/rewritelog.log"` but it gives me error 500

Comment: In apache 2.4 which you're using, that directive has been removed. You have to add `mod_rewrite.c:trace6`   to your `LogLevel` directive! Logs will be written in `/XAMPP/apache/logs/error.log`

Comment: like this? `LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace6`

Comment: You're browsing `/Portfolio/`.  Try `/Portfolio`  Instead!

Comment: in a browser this `localhost/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio` redirects to `http://localhost/New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/` and it says `The requested URL /New_Era/new_era_V20/betaV2/Portfolio/.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: in .htaccess there is one more rule before it `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding this before your rewriteRule:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much :) But why it was just Portfolio? eg About did work just fine...

Comment: @it adds slash at the end of URL of directories!